# Disable programmatic access to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Can we disable programmatic access using access key / secret key to the entire account? In case there is a security breach and the access key and secret key is exposed to the outside world, can the AWS account administrator freeze the programmatic access to the AWS account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable or delete an Access Key. You must disable access keys one at a time. There is no "global" disable or delete for access keys.

There are several types of Access Keys:

1. AWS Root User Access Keys. You should not be using these keys. If you are, issue IAM User Access Keys and delete the root keys.
2. IAM User Access Keys. These are the key types that you should use for normal access.
3. Temporary Access Keys. These keys are generated by Roles or Simple Token Service (STS). These keys are temporary and expire.

[Managing Access Keys for Your AWS Account Root User](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/managing-aws-access-keys.html)

[Managing Access Keys for IAM Users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html)

[Revoking IAM Role Temporary Security Credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_revoke-sessions.html)

Comment: Thanks, so we can't disable *all* the access keys but only those we know is exposed right? Is there any disable for all access keys of an account?

Comment: You must disable access keys one at a time. There is no "global" disable or delete for access keys. TIP: You should not be creating access keys that have access to everything in your account. You should be using Least Privilege to only issue access keys with the privileges they need. If your programs are running in the cloud, don't use access keys at all and instead use IAM Roles.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my original question - no "global" disable. And that's a great tip. Can you please edit your answer to include this statement, so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: @JohnJai - Updated my answer with your suggestion.